# How do I make a custom UITableViewCell curved?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Like the Settings app, or a UITableCellStyleValue1?

I'm basically trying to replicate the tableviews in Settings.app, where you have a label and a textfield. I'm stuck trying to make the cells curved. How can I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a table view with the grouped, not the plain style and you will get the rounded table cells for free.

```
[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```